# "Nightmare" derivation

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-formation

I did some research about word *nightmare*. In most cases this is what I've found:

> *night* + Old English *mære* "incubus."

I would like to use the word *mare* for poetic purposes, but its meaning in the modern English is *an adult female horse or the female of other equine species.*

Is there any possibility to use the word *maere*, excluding the grapheme "æ", for *nightmare*?

Comment: You can use whatever words you like, but if you use "MAERE" very few native English speakers will understand it.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18431/what-were-nightmares-called-before-nightmare-was-used-in-that-sense

Comment: If you are to use either, I recommend *mare*.  At least, in that case, its relation to *nightmare* will be more transparent.

Comment: http://www.pinterest.com/booknut101/storyboard-nightmaere/

Comment: i think that if you share your verses it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: In the UK these days, the word "mare" is probably used more as a shortened form of "nightmare" than it is to mean "female horse". At least, among non-horsey people.

Comment: As a BrE native speaker living in the UK I contest @Rupe's assertion.  If someone were to say to me "I had an awful mare last night" I would think that they had been up to something horribly horsey.

Comment: @Rupe so would a bad dream about horses be called a 'mare mare'?

Answer (score 1):

You could get away with **'mare** if you are facing a syllable constraint, at the risk of sounding forced.